# Read XML file in flat file in Java

Tags: java

I am reading a file that is in xml format (has elements, attribute,..).  However, the contents in the file have no carriage return or space and all the contents are in one line.

I am searching for an element and will need to parse the value of the element.

I am thinking to use XMLStreamReader to read and parse the value.

Does it matter if the contents are in all in one line?  Or, is there another way I should look into?

Thanks.

Comment: XML is a *structured* document not a flat file by any definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't matter that all the contents are on one line - whitespace such as carriage returns will be ignored by XML parsers!

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't matter. what will happen is when parser creates DOM structure it will ignore the while space or newline element. XMLStreamReader treats a content as an event So if you dont have spaces it won't get fired to space or newline event. it will just return your xml elements.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter if the contents have whitespace between elements or not.

```
<foo><bar></bar></foo>
```

Is the same as

```
<foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#next%28%29) on XMLStreamReader you shouldn't have any problems.  You just call next() and it will iterate to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this............

If the file is in XML Format, `whether all the xml script is in one line or divided into` `multiple lines, its` **ONE AND THE SAME.......**

**To parse** the XML File, **use one of the following**

**1.** SAX (SIMPLE XMAL PARSER)

**2.** DOM (DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL)

**3.** PULL PARSER